# Allow user to set its location using Google Map and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show current location of user. After that, I also want to allow user to set its location by using (dragging) marker which will be available there.
It is same as like we add place on `Google Map`. I know how to display markers but don't have idea about to add location. I tried google but din't find any solution.
I already have `Google API` which I am using in displaying markers.
For i.e. I am at `Latitude 18.9750` and `Longitude 72.8258` which is of city Mumbai, India. It will show me my current location when I open page. Now, I also want that I can change its `Latitude` and `Longitude` by dragging `Marker` at another position.

Comment: add location to what?

Comment: @Dr.Molle, i.e. I am at some location say at any street of Mumbai, India. I will able to see it in app with marker. Now, I want that i can change location to some another street of Mumbai or any other city, any country by using marker. I hope you got my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take a shot at helping even though I currently can't test it out myself. Have you tried assigning the latitude and longitude like this...

```
 var usa = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891);
 var brasil = new google.maps.LatLng(-14.235004, -51.92528);
 var argentina = new google.maps.LatLng(-38.416097, -63.616672);
```

The Google API should have a class called something similar to google.maps.LatLng where is should be relatively simple from there to assign your latitude and Longitude.

I used code from here [How to set google map marker by latitude and longitude and provide infomation bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319488/how-to-set-google-map-marker-by-latitude-and-longitude-and-provide-infomation-bu)

Comment: What is user want to change its default location by positioning marker ?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question where you can retrieve the lat and long on a marker.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968559/retrieve-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-draggable-pin-via-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: I think it will solve my problem for sure. Let me check it once properly. If it solves my problem then i will mark ur reply as answer. :)